# Sunmi V1s device - Java callback doesn't work when the printer is done printing

Tags: java, android, callback

I'm using Sunmi V1s device and want to show a Dialog once the printer finished printing the whole receipt. I now can get a message once the query is done processing, but I cannot get the message the exact moment when the printer is done the whole printing.

I used demo app to create a Callback which I then send to an AidlUtil class.

**TextActivity**

```
final PrinterCallback printerCallback = new PrinterCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onReturnString(String result) {
                System.out.println("Finished: " + result); //never prints out, expecting this line to work when Sunmi printer finishes printing
          }

          @Override
          public void onRunResult(boolean success) {
                System.out.println("Success: " + success); //prints out immediately after query is sent
          }
          @Override
          public void onRaiseException(String msg) {

          }
};
AidlUtil.getInstance().printText(content, size, isBold, isUnderLine, printerCallback);
```

**AidlUtil class:**

```
public void printText(String content, float size, boolean isBold, boolean isUnderLine, PrinterCallback printerCallback) {
        if (woyouService == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.toast_2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            if (isBold) {
                woyouService.sendRAWData(ESCUtil.boldOn(), null);
            } else {
                woyouService.sendRAWData(ESCUtil.boldOff(), null);
            }

            if (isUnderLine) {
                woyouService.sendRAWData(ESCUtil.underlineWithOneDotWidthOn(), null);
            } else {
                woyouService.sendRAWData(ESCUtil.underlineOff(), null);
            }

            woyouService.printTextWithFont(content, null, size, generateCB(printerCallback)); //generating ICallback and sending it to printTextWithFont method
            woyouService.lineWrap(3, null);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

**generateCB method:**

```
public ICallback generateCB(final PrinterCallback printerCallback){
        return new ICallback.Stub(){
            @Override
            public void onRunResult(boolean isSuccess) throws RemoteException {
                printerCallback.onRunResult(isSuccess);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReturnString(String result) throws RemoteException {
                printerCallback.onReturnString(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRaiseException(int code, String msg) throws RemoteException {
                printerCallback.onRaiseException(msg);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrintResult(int code, String msg) throws RemoteException {
            }
        };
}
```

What can be an issue? I expect to get a System.out.println onReturnString method, but the method is not called anytime

Comment: I am also facing this issue, did u find a solution/workaround for this?